# WP import data from file at server side and pick each data to echo

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm developing a wordpress plugin for a site with a private page for each member. Inside the plugin folder I want to include a directory with a text file for each member from where some data will be retrieved upon page load and populated into certain divs. I do not want this file to be accessible by the user so I guess that xml or json files should be discarded.

1. Which method will allow me import data from a "text" file and hide it from the user?
2. How can I pick which lines from this function will be echoed into the div?

Sorry for my terrible code, I'm still learning

```
jQuery('#myDiv').text('<?php echo get_user_file_data(); ?>');



    add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_user_file_data', 'get_user_file_data' );
    function get_user_file_data() {
        include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/myfile.txt');
        $myFile = "myfile.txt";
        $lines = file($myFile);//file in to an array
        var_dump($lines);

        foreach($lines as $line) 
        {
            $var = explode(':', $line, 2);
            $arr[$var[0]] = $var[1];
        }
        return $arr;
    }
```

Comment: If this is meant to be secure, you'll need to add some sort of password security (at least add a **nonce**), or check a capability on the user's account (use **current_user_can**), because otherwise anyone could request that AJAX endpoint and get data from it. You'll also want to store this data in your database instead of in text files - this will be a bit more secure, much faster, and much easier to manage. Store only the relevant data for each user in separate rows, and use the user's ID to identify each row. That way you don't have to filter a larger text file down to the relevant lines.